# ToString() and debugger's string visualizer

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In a watch window, any string fields have a string visualizer icon (it allows to view the whole string, not only it's first chars). Any fields which have ToString() method are shown in string form, but without string visualizer, so watch window doesn't have button to view the whole text of this field. And this sucks.
Is there any way to make VS to show string visualizer button for ToString'ed fields?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it's wrong and it got votes. After digging around a bunch, I'm left with the conclusion that you can't do this. While you can make a custom visualizer, that would only work if your object is Serializable. I hope someone with a better working knowledge of VS visualization can answer this for you.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I get what you mean, consider that ToString is defined on the root object class so all its descendant have it. if in the watch window you enter a field/variable name you could see the content, if you are not satisfied you could add the .ToString() after the variable name.